# context menu strip within another context menu

Tags: vb.net, contextmenu

[image]

hi guys can any one pls help me with this thanks
Im using vb.nwt 2010

I wanted to create a context menu that shows another context menu when the item is clicked
I already have the running code for the first context menu but im lost at showing another context menu within the first one 
thanks any help will be appriciated

Comment: Are you using contextmenu or menustrip

Comment: im using context menu

Comment: why you can try menustrip

Comment: actually im very new to vb.net is there no way that i can do this on a context menu?

Comment: context menu only for right click the menu showing

Comment: thanks can you show me some sample codes on how to do that because I have really no idea on how to accomplish this thanks

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/vb.net/vb.net_menustrip.htm

Comment: the items that  are in the context menu are added depending on the clicked cell of a data grid view

Comment: mainly used for add,delete,edit row in datagridview

Answer (score 0):

If what you are asking is 'Can I create a sub menu on a context menu in the same way that a standard menu has one (as per my illustration)?'  then the answer is yes.  Just use the ContextMenuStrip control which you can find under the Menus & Toolbars strip in the toolbox panel in visual studio.

Set up the context menu the way that you wish it to be and then assign that context menu as the context menu of whichever control you want to invoke it at runtime.